# Telerik HyperLink Handler

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

How to add hyperlink handler handler so that I may redirect to any page on the internet? The hyperlinks are in the RadGridView.
The value of link, like www.google.com, are coming from database.
I'm using winform telerik.

Answer (score 2):

You must register to the `HyperlinkOpening` event of the `RadGridView`.  And you must also make the column holding the hyperlink(s) a column of type `GridViewHyperlinkColumn`.

Once you have the column created you can register as such:

```
radGridView.HyperlinkOpening += radGridView_HyperlinkOpening;

private void radGridView_HyperlinkOpening(object sender, HyperlinkOpeningEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: I don't have the authority to up vote. Anyone with less than 15 reputation are not allow to up vote.

Comment: Sorry but it's a developers community no one should make reputation by saying to vote him/ her.

Comment: Got it. Thank You. :)